# GET /groups/{id}/notes/sections/{id}/pages is giving wrong content URL for pages. The get on that request will is giving 400

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

We are using Onenote graph API extensively in our application. We do get section pages by calling this endpoint to get the list of pages.

```
GET /groups/{id}/notes/sections/{id}/pages
```

And then for every page we do a query on the contentUrl returned from the above request. This was working till last Friday fine. It does not work any longer and the reason is following.

The contentUrl returned from the above request for every pages is this.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/1666aff3-d025-479d-9792-3e645d3a9f20/onenote/pages/1-c7a8693bdd8a4e3ca9c784f159ac84e9!213-715180a6-df2a-49c8-ad43-83454d16b59d/content

If I replace the Onenote from the URL to notes, which is as per the documentation the call to this endpoint works fine (following URL works)

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/1666aff3-d025-479d-9792-3e645d3a9f20/notes/pages/1-c7a8693bdd8a4e3ca9c784f159ac84e9!213-715180a6-df2a-49c8-ad43-83454d16b59d/content

This is failing a main important flow for our application.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the Onenote API. Have you contacted the developers about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: We've transitioned our API from .../notes/... to .../onenote/... in graph. This transition is complete.

---

The reason you are seeing this now is that we are making a change in the graph api URLs for onenote - they will change from graph.microsoft.com/.../notes/... to graph.microsoft.com/.../onenote/..., as you noticed in the URLs above.

Therefore, sometime soon, you will need to update your application code to target that URL. Due to the nature of our beta API in graph.microsoft.com, it is still undergoing some changes - once we go to v1.0, you should not expect any of those breaking changes. If you're looking for a stable alternative in the meantime, our API in https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/groups/... is an API with the same functionality as the one you're using in graph that you can expect not to change.

That said, the inconsistency in returned URLs that you point out above is a bug that we have fixed now, even though the change to /onenote from /notes will happen soon.

Comment: Is there any estimated date when this changes will  be done?

Comment: This should happen tomorrow.